# cacti rrd file - NaN values

Tags: redhat, cacti

I have a small problem with **my rrd file**, I am trying to put it on cacti graph  but is not working properly.

**1.** I tried to **rrdtool update manualy rrd file** and **last_ds** is modified but **values** not.

[image]

**2.** Poller is setup on crontab at 5 min so I have setup **step = 300** and **heartbeat = 600**

**3.** Here is my cacti log :

[image]

**4.** Permission rights for every rrd file

[image]

**5.** Data source debug :

[image]

My question is *"What I am doing wrong?"*

Comment: Please post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable

Comment: I made it, now it's ok. I spent 4 hours to learn "how to cacti", how to debug and how to configure. Thank you so much

Comment: If you found something that could help others with the same problem, you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: I will do it, I will post entire tutorial